# Releasing a lock on a table in toad for oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I did a select for update statement on a table in toad for oracle and it put a lock on that table.

How can I release this lock. (I don't have DBA access)..

Does doing a commit automatically release that lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, either a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK` will release the lock.

If the table is still locked after you issue a `ROLLBACK`, it is *not* locked by you.  Here is the query I use to determine who is waiting for whom.  There are lots of other ways to do this, but this one works for me.

```
SELECT s.SID,
       s.serial#,
       s.blocking_session,
       s.final_blocking_session,
       s.event,
       s.module,
       s.action,
       s.sql_id,
       o.NAME locked_object,
       -- This is commented out because sometimes you'll get an invalid row id.  So I only put it in when I need it
--       CASE
--          WHEN s.row_wait_obj# <> -1 THEN DBMS_ROWID.rowid_create (1,
--                                                                   s.row_wait_obj#,
--                                                                   s.row_wait_file#,
--                                                                   s.row_wait_block#,
--                                                                   s.row_wait_row#)
--          ELSE NULL
--       END locked_row_id,
       s.wait_class,
       s.seconds_in_wait,
       s.state,
       s.osuser,
       s.client_identifier,
       sq.sql_text,
       sq.sql_fulltext
FROM   v$session s,
       SYS.obj$ o,
       v$sql sq 
WHERE  (   blocking_session IS NOT NULL
        OR SID IN (SELECT blocking_session
                   FROM   v$session))
AND    o.obj#(+) = s.row_wait_obj#
and    sq.sql_id = s.sql_id
```

Comment: I had actually tried commit and rollback.. but neither killed that lock on that table. Could it be because i executed select... for update.. but never actually updated the record?..

Comment: thats weird.. because i still had the locks there even after rollback. I used the session browser and in the locks tab, there was to locks both under my name.  one was a DHL lock (ROW-X(SX) and other one was Transcaction (exclusive). Under owner it said WMSADMIN ( i dont have admin privilages though)

Comment: who ever the owner is .. they have to do a commit/rollback ... maybe?..

Comment: The `ROLLBACK` must be issued from the session that locked the rows to begin with.  No other sessions are relevant.

Comment: Is it possible you have two sessions open in TOAD?

Comment: what if i had closed the instance of TOAD that issued the lock with out a rollback..  I think thats probably what happend..

Comment: I asked the DBAs to kil that lock and they were able to do it.. but still trying to understand how it happend..

Comment: Depending on how TOAD closed it, then you may need to wait for Oracle's PMON process to clean it up.  You can get the SID of the lock holder(s) on that table by checking `DBA_LOCKS`.  The `lock_type` will be "DML" and the LOCK_ID1 will be the object ID (from `DBA_OBJECTS`) of your table.  Check there and see what the `SID` is.

Comment: One last thing.  In Oracle 12c, you can `GRANT READ ON table_name TO user_name` instead of `GRANT SELECT ON...`.  It's the same thing except you cannot `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`.